# Xamarin.Mobile Camera image stream

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin.mobile

I am trying to use the new http://xamarin.com/mobileapi and (while awesome) I can't find the functionality I need - I need to access the camera stream and sample it. Using the `MediaPicker` class I can get video and images but I need to analyze the live video stream.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Xamarin.Mobile does not give you the ability to process the live video stream, you have to use the API provided by each platform to accomplish this.

You can file an [enhancement request](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Xamarin%20Mobile%20API%20Preview) if you think it should be added to Xamarin.Mobile.

Comment: I have. It's critical for a project I'm implementing so I'm still hoping for a cross platform solution.

Comment: @Shy, did you ever find a way to do this on iOS?

Comment: I did but i didn't use Xamarin.Mobile.
take a look at https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile - it's a good implementation.